# How to unmount vuejs instance from DOM

Tags: vue.js

Is there any way to unmount vuejs Instance from DOM?
I want to mount and unmount the Vue instance for suited condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an vm.unmount() method on Vue 3 instance. If you are using Vue 2 you can use vm.$destroy().

If you are using file template you can use v-if condition on your component. That will remove element from DOM based on condition.

Comment: thanks, but sadly I'm using vuetify that doesn't support vue3 yet.

Comment: i tried vm.$destroy() but not completely destroying instance. I think the third option might work

Comment: The recommended one is the third one by the way. I' ve never used vm.unmount() and vm.$destroy(). If you are making SPA you've mostly never need that.

Comment: the requirement is I have to only load Vue instance for some suited condition otherwise I don't want to mount Vue instance.

Comment: Actually i need to see your code to answer. <custom-component v-if="yourCondition" /> if yourCondition false the Vue instance is not gonna mount.

Answer (score 1):

@gurkan-ugurlu third option works well.

My requirement was to mount and unmount the Vue instance. but it turns out, it was to render the DOM element for the suited condition for that template condition works well.

by searching, I understood that template conditions like if-else actually render the component. it's not like applying CSS property `display: none;`